# POST METHOD is not working but not showing any Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am new to PHP. I am using below code in my project but its not working but its not throwing any error. I tried to convert it to GET method but still its not working too.

PHP is my frontend and MYSQL database is the backend.

I have already created the table in the back end and I checked the user table but values are not inserted too.

Methods Tried:

I have inserted data manually using insert command and its working fine.

**API Call**

```
http://localhost/test/register.php?phone=12345&name=Smith&birthdate=1974-12-01&address=7th Avenue
```

**Error:**

```
{"error_msg":"Required parameter (phone,name,birthdate,address) is missing!"}
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'db_functions.php';
$db=new DB_Functions();
$response=array();
if(isset($_POST['phone']) &&
isset($_POST['name']) &&
isset($_POST['birthdate']) &&
isset($_POST['address']))

{
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $birthdate=$_POST['birthdate'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];

    if($db->checkExistsUser($phone))
    {
        $response["error_msg"]="User already exists with" .$phone;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
       //Create new user
        $user=$db->registerNewUser($phone,$name,$birthdate,$address);

        if($user)
        {
            $response["phone"]=$user["Phone"];
            $response["name"]=$user["Name"];
            $response["birthdate"]=$user["Birthdate"];
            $response["address"]=$user["Address"];

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        else
        {
            $response["error_msg"]="Unknown Error occurred in registration!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }

}
else
{
    $response["error_msg"]="Required parameter (phone,name,birthdate,address) is missing!";
    echo  json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

**CheckUser.PHP**

```
<?php
require_once 'db_functions.php';
$db=new DB_Functions();
$response=array();
if(isset($_POST['phone']))
{
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];

    if($db->checkExistsUser($phone))
    {
        $response["exists"]=TRUE;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
        $response["exists"]=FALSE;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

}
else
{
    $response["error_msg"]="Required parameter (phone) is missing!";
    echo  json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

**db_functions.php**

```
<?php


class DB_Functions
{
    private $conn;

    function __construct()
    {
        require_once  'db_connect.php';
        $db=new DB_Connect();
        $this->conn=$db->connect();
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        // TODO: Implement __destruct() method.

    }

    /*
     * Check user exists
     * return true/false
     */

    function checkExistsUser($phone)
    {
        $stmt=$this->conn->prepare("select * from User where Phone=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$phone);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        }

        else{
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }


    /*
     * Register new user
     * return User Object if user was created
     * Return error mssage if have exception
     */


    public function registerNewUser($phone,$name,$birthdate,$address)
    {
        $stmt=$this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO User(Phone,Name,Birthdate,Address) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$phone,$name,$birthdate,$address);
        $result=$stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();


        if($result)
        {
            $stmt=$this->$this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM User where Phone = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$phone);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user=$stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();
            return $user;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

**db_connect.php**

```
<?php

class DB_Connect{

    private $conn;

    public function connect()

    {
        require_once 'config.php';
        $this->conn=new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
        return $this->conn;
    }

}

?>
```

Name, Phone, Address and Dateofbirth value need to be inserted in MYSQL database.

Comment: Where is your HTML form? Can you show it to us too? Maybe you just made a typo or not specified the right method.

Comment: How did you send the request? can you add the form?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I have added the API call as well.

Comment: Replace all `$_POST` with `$_GET` as you're passing query parameters

Comment: Even if change it to GET its throwing me a undefined variable phone, birthdate, addres and name variable. Its not working for me.

Comment: What do you get if you vardump `$_GET`?

Comment: @kuh-chan. I converted everything to get and there was a small typo in the db_connection statement. $stmt=$this->$this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM User where Phone = ?");

Comment: Can I use POST to post values in PHP or not?

Comment: Yes, you can use POST in PHP, but the API URL you've shown is using GET parameters.

Comment: How to convert  GET method to POST in my code?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to keep using the URL like you have it (with `?phone=XXX&name=YYY` and so on)? If so, that's a GET, not a POST, and that's how your code has to handle it.

Comment: "How to convert GET method to POST in my code"...since we can't see what code was used to generate the URL, we can't tell you

Comment: No problem. If you show us that code we can help you change it so it makes a POST request instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL call is GET method, but you are querying POST variables.

So basically your if statement resulted to false hence the error message. Change them to GET.

```
if(isset($_GET['phone']) &&
isset($_GET['name']) &&
isset($_GET['birthdate']) &&
isset($_GET['address']))
```

Then it should work